# VS2015 Windows Form + MySql read and compare value from DB

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, mysql-workbench

I used to do some smaller programming projects before but now I want to retry and get back into this.

I use Visual Studio 2015 - Windows Forms Application VB.net
MySql Workbench

I have made a login system which reads from MySql which I got working.

What I want now is that, I have an "Admin" Tab in my program, but when I press this. I only want the users with a "4" or above in the groups column of MySql to have access, I got stuck here and cant find how I should do it.
I will paste the code of my login as I done it currently.

Here is my login code and at the bottom I want the

```
Private Sub TabAdmin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabAdmin.Click
```

To check if the user will have access or not

http://pastebin.com/8x2MP66G

If you look at this when it works, user "Admin" will have access to Admintab,
while user NotAdmin will not get access

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNhsV.png

I hope I was clear enough and that someone can help me out here :)

Comment: Forgot to add my code, but this is how it looks http://pastebin.com/8x2MP66G

Comment: This seems to be `VB.Net`, not C#

Comment: You are very correct, VB.Net is what Im using not C#